# SWIG - Problem with namespaces

Tags: c++, python, macos, namespaces, swig

I'm having trouble getting the following simple example to work with SWIG 1.3.40 (and I also tried 1.3.31). The Foo structure comes through as a Python module as long as I don't wrap it in a namespace, but as soon as I do I get a compilation error in the generated **test_wrap.c**.

test.h:

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

#define USE_NS 1

#if USE_NS
namespace ns {
#endif

struct Foo {
  float a;
  float b;
  float func();
};

#if USE_NS
}
#endif

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

#if USE_NS
namespace ns {
#endif

float Foo::func()
{
  return a;
}

#if USE_NS
}
#endif
```

test.i

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

I run the following commands for building a bundle on OSX 10.6.3:

```
swig -python test.i
g++ -c -m64 -fPIC test.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers test_wrap.c
g++ -o _test.so -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress test_wrap.o test.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lpython2.6
```

This works, but only if I take out the namespace. I though SWIG handled namespaces automatically in simple cases like this. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error that I get - it looks like SWIG references a 'ns' and a 'namespace' symbol which are undefined.

```
test_wrap.c: In function ‘int Swig_var_ns_set(PyObject*)’:
test_wrap.c:2721: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
test_wrap.c:2721: error: expected primary-expression before ‘namespace’
test_wrap.c:2721: error: expected `)' before ‘namespace’
test_wrap.c:2721: error: expected `)' before ‘;’ token
test_wrap.c: In function ‘PyObject* Swig_var_ns_get()’:
test_wrap.c:2733: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
test_wrap.c:2733: error: expected `)' before ‘void’
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part(s) of the generated file test_wrap.c? And note that g++ looks by default at the file extensions to determine which language the file is in, so test_wrap.c will be compiled as C code, not as C++.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your test.i file, add a "using namespace ns" line after the #include. Without that, your swig wrapper code won't know to look for Foo in the "ns" namespace.

Comment: What is a namespace is inside a namespace, in the C++ header. How do you handle that in the interface file. For example `namespace school { namespace college { .... .... .... } }`

Comment: @nikk `using namespace school::college;`, possibly together with `using namespace school;`

Comment: @gabrielburca: your answer also solved my error with a namespace that "has not been declared". Many thanks!