# How to automatically remove the namespace attached to a friend function defined within a C++ class, when using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to wrap a C++ class designed by a colleague of mine, using SWIG, for scripting programming in Python. These classes are defined as a bunch of source files which I have, but do not want to modify.

All the classes are defined within a given namespace and include friend functions, for global treatment on its objects without having to use methods on any of the objects.

SWIG complains about the fact that the automatic identifier generated for such functions cannot be wrapped automatically (`Warning 503: Can't wrap 'ns::inf' unless renamed to a valid identifier.`. See below code). And, when I use the `%rename` keyword in the SWIG interface file (`%rename(inf) ns::inf;`. See below), the Python library file is correctly generated, but not the C++ `.cxx` intermediate file. The new error is then:

```
mwe_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_inf(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
mwe_wrap.cxx:3369:16: error: ‘inf’ is not a member of ‘ns’
 3369 |   result = ns::inf((ns::mwe const &)*arg1,(ns::mwe const &)*arg2);
      |                ^~~
```

I have reduced my problem to a minimal working example (with which I got the preceding error messages), available in the following files extracts.

**mwe.cpp**

```
#include "mwe.h"

namespace ns
{   mwe::mwe(void) {
        a = 1;
        b = -1;
    }

    mwe::mwe(long par1, long par2) {
        a = par1;
        b = par2;
    }

    mwe inf(const mwe &obj1, const mwe &obj2)
    {
        mwe objtemp(obj1.a, obj1.b);
        if (obj2.a > obj1.a) objtemp.a = obj2.a;
        if (obj2.b < obj1.b) objtemp.b = obj2.b;

        return(objtemp);
    }
}
```

**mwe.h**

```
#ifndef __MWE_H__
#define __MWE_H__

namespace ns
{
    class mwe {
    protected:
        long a;
        long b;

    public:
        mwe(void);
        mwe(long, long);

        friend mwe inf(const mwe &, const mwe &);
    };
}
#endif
```

**mwe.i**

```
// Module name
%module mwe

// Header
%rename(newinf) ns::inf;

// The following block is compulsory, because of the use of the `ns` namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3762478/7009806
%{
    #include "mwe.h"
%}

%include "mwe.h"
```

My compilation commands are the following ones (getting advantage of [python-config](https://packages.debian.org/trixie/python-dev-is-python3)):

```
swig -c++ -python -Wall mwe.i
g++ -fPIC -c -Wall mwe_wrap.cxx $(python-config --cflags)
```

How can I manage to **automatically** remove the `ns::` namespace from the generated `inf` function in `mwe_wrap.cxx` (at line 3369 on my system)?

As a comparison, this function is correctly generated with the specified new name in `mwe.py`:

```
def newinf(arg1, arg2):
    return _mwe.newinf(arg1, arg2)
```

I **really** thought the `.Py` and `.cxx` would be consistent on such a matter. In facts, if I remove that `ns::` *manually* and keep on compiling the shared object library and finally load it into Python, everything works as a charm (using `newinf`). Could it be some bug of some sort?

Comment: Is it only a warning?  Does the code actually work as intended?

Comment: As written in the first terminal extract, it is an actual *error*. There is a *manual* workaround that I described at the end of my question, but I definitely would like to find an **automatic** solution to this problem, using the correct SWIG primitive or whatever, and without having to modify the original C++ files. The "503 warning" from SWIG was telling me the `inf` function would not be wrapped at all, before I added the `%rename` primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is indeed not really warranted. Make an issue on github and I will look into it. The `friend` is the problem.

However there is no other problem in SWIG besides this warning.

Your C++ declaration is not really complete. A `friend` is not a declaration in itself. You should declare this function. Your header should be:

```cpp
#ifndef __MWE_H__
#define __MWE_H__

namespace ns {

class mwe {
protected:
  long a;
  long b;

public:
  mwe(void);
  mwe(long, long);

  friend mwe inf(const mwe &, const mwe &);
};

mwe inf(const mwe &, const mwe &);
} // namespace ns
#endif
```

If you do this, you will still get the warning, but the code will be correct and `ns::inf` will be automatically renamed to `inf`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction (which I investigated and found more explanation [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703612/7009806), in case people would like more insight)! Then, the code gets correctly wrapped in Python. I will have to tell my colleagues to improve their code... I indeed still get a couple of "302 warnings" with the `swig` command, for which I will raise an issue on Github in a close future.